# JSLint errors: Undeclared 'Image', Undeclared 'Document', out of scope

Tags: javascript, jslint

With very basic javascript knowledge I built a simple slideshow (code below). It works but JSLint shows the following errors:

- **Undeclared 'Image'** slideimages[0] = new Image();
- **Undeclared 'setInterval'** setInterval(myCounter, 50);
- **'myCounter' is out of scope** setInterval(myCounter, 50);
- **Undeclared 'document'** document.getElementById('slide').src =slideimages[step].src;

How can I overcome those issues e.g. declare those elements?

```
var slideimages = [];

slideimages[0] = new Image();
slideimages[0].src = "http://placehold.it/350x150?text=Welcome";
slideimages[1] = new Image();
slideimages[1].src = "imgs/slide_1.png";
slideimages[2] = new Image();
slideimages[2].src = "imgs/slide_2.png";


var step = 0;

var c = 0;
var a = 0;
setInterval(myCounter, 50);
function myCounter() {

    'use strict';

document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src;

    if ((c >= 0) && (c < 40)) {
        c += 1;
        a = c;
        step = 1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a / 100;
document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = a / 40;

    } else if ((c >= 40) && (c < 80)) {

        c += 1;
        a = c;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a / 100;
document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = 1;

    } else if ((c >= 80) && (c < 100)) {

        c += 1;
        a = c;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 1 - ((a - 80) / 20);
document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = 1 - ((a - 80) / 20);

    } else if ((c >= 100) && (c < 140)) {

        c += 1;
        a = c;
        step = 2;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a / 100;
document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = (a - 100) / 40;

    } else if ((c >= 140) && (c < 180)) {

        c += 1;
        a = c;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a / 100;
document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = 1;

    } else if ((c >= 180) && (c < 200)) {

        c += 1;
        a = c;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 1 - ((a - 180) / 20);
document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = 1 - ((a - 180) / 20);

    } else {
        c = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LSLint doesn't allow browser-related things by default. Thus,

```
Undeclared 'Image' slideimages[0] = new Image();
Undeclared 'setInterval' setInterval(myCounter, 50);
Undeclared 'document' document.getElementById('slide').src =slideimages[step].src;
```

Look at jslint options, and [assume browser](http://www.jslint.com/help.html#browser) in special.